# Azure Powershell Scripts Fail Siliently

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure

I've been working with the Azure Powershell scripts from Microsoft over the last new days and am becoming frustrated with how often they seem to fail silently or give very misleading error messages. I have tried using the -verbose option, but this isn't very verbose.

Does any have any tips of things I can try to beef up the feedback when something goes wrong?

For example: Save-AzureServiceProjectPackage is reporting that the cloud_package.cspkg is created but no file is created on disk. If I delete my node_modules folder it works correctly and reports the same thing!

I've raised this direct with the team, but it appears the problem is with cspack.exe which the powershell calls: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2689

Comment: Generic PS advice: add `-ErrorAction Stop` switch to `Save-AzureServiceProjectPackage`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give me much as when I add this the script stops earlier but still does not produce an error

Comment: After the error execute this: `$error[0] |fl * -Force`. It will return all the information from the last error on the the error stack, including (in some cases) a stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems.

**What didn't work:** to install the latest SDK for Azure (Libraries for .NET and Azure Powershell)

**What did work:** to shorten the longest directory path.
For instance, in your deepest subdirectories, you delete everything not needed. Or move your $DEV_ROOT directory to the drive's top level. It's not a nice solution though.